# Is home distillation of beer or wine on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about home distillation of home brewed beer and/or wine to be considered as on-topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Informally, it is not on-topic, looking at other distillation questions and their closing by moderators. Apart from the fact that it's very broadly illegal world-wide (with a couple of notable exceptions), it also is a set of techniques, equipment and skills that are outside the normal wort-production and fermentation process.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is a [distillation](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distillation) tag with 22 questions, perhaps this question should be reanswered?